# How to define measure over infinite sequence of random variables

Tags: probability-theory, measure-theory, probability-distributions

Suppose we are drawing elements from a set $\Omega$ at each time $t\in \mathbb N$. The probability of drawing $\omega\in \Omega$ at time $t$ is given by a conditional distribution $\mu(\omega|\omega_1,\omega_2,\ldots,\omega_{t-1})$ (the function $(\omega_1,\omega_2,\ldots,\omega_{t-1})\to \mu(B|\omega_1,\omega_2,\ldots,\omega_{t-1}) $ is measurable in $\Omega^{t-1}$ for each $B\subseteq \Omega$). How does one formally define the joint probability measure over a realization of an infinite sequence of draws such that the probability of any finite sequence of draws corresponds to the one given by the joint measure induced by the $\mu$'s?

Does anyone have a reference for this type of construction?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The [Kolmogorov Extension Theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kolmogorov_extension_theorem) may be able to help. The "Implications of the Theorem" section seems relevant to your question here. It's not constructive at the infinite level, but provides a formalism to link the finite to the infinite.